# webdriver opera, ValueError: API Rate limit exceeded. You have to add GH_TOKEN

Tags: selenium-webdriver

guys!!! I have a problem, I'm trying to access whatsapp with webdriver and in the browser opera, but the error appears

ValueError: API rate limit exceeded. You have to add GH_TOKEN!!!

I googled https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/blob/master/README.md#use-with-opera

But I didn't find the solution. In Google Chrome works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd5nz.png)

Comment: [WDM] - = WebDriver manager =
[WDM] - Current firefox version is 101.0
[WDM] - Get LATEST geckodriver version for 101.0 firefox
[WDM] - GH_TOKEN will be used to perform requests
- Captured log setup --
INFO     WDM:logger.py:16 =WebDriver manager =
INFO     WDM:logger.py:16 Current firefox version is 101.0
INFO     WDM:logger.py:16 Get LATEST geckodriver version for 101.0 firefox
INFO     WDM:logger.py:16 GH_TOKEN will be used to perform requests
==short test summary info =
ERROR test_e2e.py::TestFirst::test_e2e - ValueError: API Rate limit exceeded. You have to add GH_TOKEN!!!

Comment: I am also facing this same issue with selenium python

Answer (score 0):

Errors are caused by not using a `GH_TOKEN` and the API timing out (max 60 requests/hr for unauthenticated users.

The `webdriver_manager` docs outline the potential issues you have ran into here.

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#configuration

I ran into similar issues but whilst attempting to run this as apart of a Github Action. It all ran fine locally, and ran fine a few times as a part of the Github Action, but eventually stopped working.

---

This can be fixed by adjusting your `.github/workflows/ACTION.yml` file (noting  the `.yml` file can be called whatever you like).

```yaml
name: Your Github Action

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 3 * * 2'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'
        required: true
        default: 'warning' 
        type: choice
        options:
        - info
        - warning
        - debug 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/labeler@v2
      with:
        repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
        
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
        
    - name: Run Your webdriver based task
      env:
        # This is the important line to add
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: python script.py
```

The 2nd last line here is the important part. You can use the standard `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable that is exposed by default to your Github Action. Or you can choose to setup your own, if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use ChromeDriver instead of Geckodriver. It worked for me.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.